# How to pass arguments raw and unprocessed to R script

Tags: r, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to trigger a R script as a job in an azure pipeline. One of the command line arguments I want to pass is a json object. The command looks like this:
`Rscript code/script.R "[{element1:"val1",element2:"val2"},{element1:"val01,element2:"val02"}`
Now, when I read the arguments in the R script and try to make an object out of the json like this:

```
library(jsonlite)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
params <- args[1]
obj <- fromJSON(params)
```

I get an error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                     [{element1:val1,el
                     (right here) ------^
```

Somehow, the quotation marks get dropped from the entire string. In the documentation of the `commandArgs()`function I found this:

> These arguments are captured before the standard R command line processing takes place. This means that they are the unmodified values.

So what am I doing wrong? Can I pass the argument without losing quotation marks or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order for the script to not ignore/parse out the quotation marks, they need to be escaped. The escape characters are lost once during the whole process (somewhere between logic app and the pipeline) so I needed to stringify the object twice before sending it to the pipeline which then makes it possible for R to read it as a valid JSON string that can be transformed into an object. Here's what it had to look like:

```
"[{\"element1\":\"val1\",\"element2\":\"val2\"},{...}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your script

```
library(jsonlite)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
params <- args[1]
obj <- fromJSON(params)
print(obj)
```

using 3 \ should work:

```
E:\R>rscript json.R "[{\\\"element1\\\":\\\"val1\\\", \\\"element2\\\":\\\"val2\\\"}]"
  element1 element2
1     val1     val2

E:\R>
```

Comment: This is weird. I tried using 3 \ on the argument and it didn't work, ran it with exactly the same argument as in your answer and still get the same error I got initially (lexical error: invalid char ...)

Comment: Maybe this is related to Azure. The above command was executed on a Windows 10 command prompt. Are you using PowerShell or bash? Escaping quotes works differently on other shells.

Comment: It could possibly be that it's related to escaping on different OS. I ran it in a docker container on mac. I have now found a way to pass the arguments in a way that the R script can handle them: One escape character was enough which is achieved by stringifying the object twice before passing it to azure. I'll add it as an answer. Thanks for your help!